# No consigo eliminar un menú de navegación con Javascript en vista de smartphone

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, display

os comento, estoy haciendo en mi portafolio un menú de navegación que cuando hagas scroll hacia abajo, éste quede fijo en la parte superior de la pantalla. El tema es que este menú de navegación fijo que se crea al scrollear hacia abajo, no lo quiero en la vista de móvil, y para ello estoy usando el siguiente código de HTML Y JS.

```
HTML)       <div id="barra_nav">

                <a href="#about-me">Sobre mí </a>
                <a href="#servicios">Skills</a>
                <a href="#portafolio">Portafolio</a>
                <a href="#contacta">Contacta conmigo</a>

            </div>
```

JS

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=>{
var navegador = document.getElementById('barra_nav');
var scroll = window.scrollY;
var texto_nav = document.querySelectorAll("#barra_nav a");


if(scroll>500){
    navegador.style.position ='fixed'
    navegador.style.top = '0';
    navegador.style.display = 'flex';
    navegador.style.justifyContent = 'space-around'
    navegador.style.width = "100%";
    navegador.style.backgroundColor = 'var(--negro)'
    navegador.style.color = '#fff'
    navegador.style.zIndex = '99999';
    
    navegador.style.transition = '1s ease-in';
    navegador.style.left='0';
    navegador.style.padding= .8+"rem";
    navegador.style.boxShadow='0 5px 10px var(--secundario)';
    navegador.style.margin=0;
    for (let i = 0; i<texto_nav.length;i++){
        
        texto_nav[i].style.fontWeight='300';
        texto_nav[i].style.color='var(--parrafos)';
        
    }
    if (window.innerWidth < 510){
        navegador.className="vacio";
    }
    
    
    
}
else{
    navegador.style.position ='relative'
    navegador.style.display = 'block';
    navegador.style.width = "100%";
    navegador.style.transition = '.1s';
    navegador.style.padding=0;
    navegador.style.marginTop=2+"rem";
    navegador.style.color = '#ffffff'
    navegador.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent'
    navegador.style.zIndex = '99999';
    navegador.style.boxShadow='none';
    
    for (let i = 0; i<texto_nav.length;i++){
        
        texto_nav[i].style.fontWeight='300';
        texto_nav[i].style.color='var(--oscuro)'
    }
    if (window.innerWidth < 510){
        navegador.style.marginTop=0;
        
        
    }
    
    
}


});
```

CSS)

```
.vacio{

display: none;}
```

Lo importante del código Javascript es la parte concreta de

```
 if (window.innerWidth < 510){
        navegador.className="vacio";
    }
```

Básicamente ahí la idea es, si mi ventana es menor a esos 510px, mi menú de navegación va a tener una clase que será vacio ya hecha en CSS, que lo que hace es un simple display none.
Pero no me está quitando el menú de navegación. La sintaxis yo creo que es la correcta, porque en el `else` estoy haciendo algo parecido con `navegador.style.marginTop=0;` Y eso lo está cogiendo sin problemas.
Alguna idea?

**EDITO**

Adjunto capturas de como está actualmente, no lo hago con CSS porque no sé plantearlo con los media, no se trata de en vista de PC que salga el menú y en vista de móvil no, ambos menús situados en el header tienen que estar, la única diferencia es que el menú fijo que creo con JS, no lo quiero en vista de smartphone.

VISTA PC

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

VISTA MÓVIL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Es muy necesario hacerlo con JS, en lugar de usar `@media` de CSS?

Comment: coincido con @padaleiana [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) creo que es mas sencillo

Comment: @padaleiana He editado el post, lo dicho, no sé plantear lo que quiero hacer a puro css con los media. También que como me estoy iniciando con JS he querido practicarlo así.

Answer (score 0):

Igualmente, como te comentaron, es mas facil usar las etiquetas @media.

Pero para ayudarte con tu inconveniente especificio, te recomiendo leer esto -->
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Fijate en particular, el metodo toggle, agrega o saca una clase.

```
navegador.classList.toggle("vacio", window.innerWidth < 510 )
```

Saludos.

**Edito tu respuesta**

La condición que me has comentado, la hace bien, entra sin problemas a distintas resolciones.

```
        if (window.innerWidth < 510){
            console.log("Estoy entrando aquí");
        }
        else{
            console.log("NO estoy entrando en el IF");
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No me está solucionando el problema, pero está interesante, no lo sabía. Quizás no lo estoy poniendo en el sitio correcto.

Comment: Mete un console.log aca adentro del if, y fijate si estas llegando-->>    }
    if (window.innerWidth < 510){
        navegador.className="vacio";
    }

Comment: window.innerWidth < 510 ¿a que resolución estas poniendo la pantalla para probar?mostra una captura del console.log por favor.

Comment: No una captura de pantalla, en texto ;)

Comment: Hola @FacundoE.Villagra te he editado tu respuesta con el texto de esa condición, y una captura del console log, entra sin problemas.

Comment: Entiendo, fijate de colocar los console log y el toggle en el mismo if que esta dentro de tu aplicacion, que esta dentro del if de scroll > 500 (dentro de 2 if anidados) , ahi creo yo que es donde no esta llegando,